# QTimer with QDragEvent problems

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qgraphicsview

I have a GUI application where you can drag widgets around in a QGraphicsView/Scene. You can also pan and zoom while you're not dragging a widget.

**What I want:**
I want to make it so that when you're dragging an item near the edge of the screen that it starts to pan in that direction and keeps panning even if the mouse isn't moving, but the mouse still needs to be in the top/left/right or bottom 10% of the screen.

**What I've tried:**
Inside the dragMoveEvent I check if the mouse is on the edge of the screen. If so I start a Qtimer with 15msec timeout. On timeout a function is slotted to pan the scene in the right direction by updating the center. This approach WORKS, BUT when i leave the mouse still on the edge the panning is choppy and if the mouse is moving around inside the edge then the panning is smooth as it should be.

**Bottom Line:**
Why is the panning only choppy/laggy when the mouse isn't moving? How do I fix it so that the panning is smooth like when you move the mouse around inside the edges?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you increase/decrease your timeout?

Comment: The lag because more noticeable when the timeout is lower and less noticeable when the timeout is higher